# I am using Pdf viewer library to open Pdf file. It shows pdf loading for a long time

Tags: android

I am tried with pdfView library and i have added pdfviewlibrary jar and everything.But it shows only "Loading PDF page". I have my pdf file in asset folder

Could any 1 please help me to find out the solution?
I have mentioned my code below

Thanks

```
package com.example.pdfviewer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends PdfViewerActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public int getPreviousPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.left_arrow; }
    public int getNextPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.right_arrow; }
    public int getZoomInImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_in; }
    public int getZoomOutImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_out; }
    public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() { return R.layout.pdf_file_password; }
    public int getPdfPageNumberResource() { return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber; }
    public int getPdfPasswordEditField() { return R.id.etPassword; }
    public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() { return R.id.btOK; }
    public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() { return R.id.btExit; }
    public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() { return R.id.pagenum_edit; }

}
```

Comment: You defined no content, is that correct? The official README just tells to add a layout inside yours: https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same problem but i solved it...
your given code is correct there is no problem in that just check the path of the file that you are taking is correct or not. In my project I making mistake on that point so may be that can solve your problem. for your reference i am giving you my code...

```
private File currentDir;
private FileArrayAdapter file_adapter;
String path;

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath") @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    currentDir = new File("/sdcard/");
    fill(currentDir);


}

 @SuppressLint("SdCardPath") private void fill(File f)
    {
        File[]dirs = f.listFiles();


         Faculty_Notes.this.setTitle("Current Dir: "+f.getName());
         List<Option>dir = new ArrayList<Option>();
         List<Option>fls = new ArrayList<Option>();
         try{
             for(File ff: dirs)
             {
                if(ff.isDirectory())
                    dir.add(new              Option(ff.getName(),"Folder",ff.getAbsolutePath()));
                else
                {
                    if(ff.getName().endsWith(".pdf"))
                    {
                        fls.add(new Option(ff.getName(),"File Size:    "+ff.length(),ff.getAbsolutePath()));
                    }

                }
             }
         }catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         Collections.sort(dir);
         Collections.sort(fls);
         dir.addAll(fls);
         if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("/sdcard"))
             dir.add(0,new Option("..","Parent Directory",f.getParent()));
         file_adapter = new   FileArrayAdapter(Faculty_Notes.this,R.layout.file_view,dir);
         Faculty_Notes.this.setListAdapter(file_adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long    id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
        Option o = file_adapter.getItem(position);
           if(o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("folder")||o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("parent directory")){
                currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
                fill(currentDir);
        }
        else
        {
            onFileClick(o);
        }
    }
    private void onFileClick(Option o)
    {
        path = o.getPath();
        openPdfIntent(path);
    }
    private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
        try {
         final Intent intent = new Intent(Faculty_Notes.this, Second.class);
         intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
         startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

also Second.class file contains the code that you have given above.

Hope this will help you good luck :)